# Why can't I see the role list in AWS Lambda Advanced Function Details dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, aws-lambda

I am creating a simple AWS Lambda Function in C# - in fact nothing more than their template.  I right click on a project, select `Publish to AWS Lambda`, fill out the function name, assembly, type names and all that, then go Next to the  Advanced Function Details dialog.

In this dialog, I am asked to provide a name.  But the drop-down is empty and there is no way to type it in.

I have plenty of roles defined in IAM and have attached them to other lambda functions (that I created in aws console).  Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check to if the IAM user you are using in Visual Studio has permissions to list roles and policies.

Comment: Which specific permissions are these?
I've added "iam:ListRolePolicies", "iam:ListRoles", and "iam:ListPolicies" and still have the empty box.

Comment: I pushed out version 1.11.3.0 of the toolkit yesterday which should now report back any errors getting the data to fill in the drop down box.