# Issue Saving an AWS Lambda Project in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I get the following message when I attempt to save an AWS lambda project in VS 2015. 
I just downloaded and installed the AWS .Net tools and SDK.  I then created a new AWS lambda(.Net Core) project and tried to save the project and got the message below.

I am able to open and save other non AWS projects.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to install the latest Visual Studio .Net Core Tools Preview.

Here is the [link to the download](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=827546).

Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020289/microsoft-dotnet-props-was-not-found) for more details.

This material, previously from an entry I created on SO Docs, may help:

1. Open Visual Studio and Select File -> New Project
2. Select AWS Lambda Project with Tests (.NET Core)
   [image]
3. Next the **Select Blueprint** screen will display.  Select **Empty Function** and Click the Finish button:
   [image]
4. Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.
5. In the console window, type [Install-Package Amazon.Lambda.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Core/)
6. Right-click your project in the solution explorer and select Restore Packages.  This is the final preparation step before you start writing code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent instructions! I was able to create the project and even tried the sample you had on the SO Documentation Draft. I see a different issue now. When I get to the window to upload the function to  AWS i.e. the "Advance Function Details" window. The drop down doesn't list any of the IAM Roles!

Comment: There was another SO post about that - let me see if I can find the link.  It had to do with the Amazon user logged into the VS AWS tool did not have the correct IAM permissions.

Comment: @user99513 here is the article:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251404/why-cant-i-see-the-role-list-in-aws-lambda-advanced-function-details-dialog